# [NSManagedObjectSubclass xxx]--unrecognized selectot sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I use the `NSManagedObjectSubclass` which Xcode auto generate, total 4 files. They are:

Doctor.h,
Doctor+CoreDataProperties.h and their implementation files.

The Doctor+CoreDataProperties.h file has all properties which contains a property 'uid' .`@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *uid;` The .m file use `@dynamic uid;`

The question
firstly, I query the Doctor instance from database like this (by using the MagicalRecord framework)

```
self.doctor = [Doctor doctorWithEasemobAccount:self.chatter withContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
```

then I get the `uid` by `self.doctor.uid`, while sometimes the app can crash with the reason

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Doctor uid]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x17428d250'

But it runs normally most of the time.

Can someone help me analysis the possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience, the `NSInvalidArgumentException` indicates that your instance (in this case Doctor) might be nil or not of the type you want.

Set a breakpoint and check the Doctor instance. You should also be handling the case where your query doesn't return anything.

(Side note: not sure why your property is `(nullable, nonatomic, retain)`, you might just want `(nonatomic, strong)` depending on your usage of `uid`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if the instance is nil, it will not throw a exception and if the instance is not the type 'Doctor'(such as a NSNull instance),the exception should be like that '-[NSNull uid]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1074be180'. So I think the reason might be that the getter method was not implemented when [Doctor uid] was called(the property uid was defined  in a class category). But I do not know why it can happen.(PS: the property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) is auto generated by Xcode)

Comment: A category can't add a property to an existing class. Unless you mean a "class extension" or "anonymous category", this is where you have `@interface ClassName ()`. The compiler automatically synthesizes the accessor methods so that shouldn't be the problem. PS: it looks like you might be running an old version of Xcode because `retain` is an old keyword

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and making sure that the Doctor instance is not nil and that in the debugger you can see the `uid` property?

Comment: I know that adding property in category won't synthesize the setter and getter method, there is also no member variable such as `_name, _uid` ... unless you use the runtime api such as `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject`.Because the category property is auto generated by Xcode,I think the Core Data should handle it inner(it use @dynamic) to make sure that we can set or get the property normally. Just I don't know how it implement that. Therefore I don't know why it can happen that the method can't be found.

Comment: I don't know whether it is right to understand like that. Please comment.(PS:code is written by Xcode7 or early version, now I use Xcode8)

Comment: I have tried setting a breakpoint to test, the Doctor instance and uid are both normal . Because it run normally most of time, it is hard to meet the happen of exception

Comment: You should then have an if-statement to make sure that the returned Doctor instance isn't nil. This could happen since the query is not guaranteed to give you a result.

Comment: It may be a good suggestion. But that does not solve my problem. If the doctor instance is nil, it will not cause crash. I still do not know the real reason of crash. Do you think?